# JQuery pagination - Index start from 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

Can anyone please help me to make this JQuery pagination index start from 1.. I tried and still trying but couldnt make it out yet.. so any help will be greatly appreciated
http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Simply changing `__id__` to `page_id + 1` in line 73 will make the index start from 1.. but that will make current page logic go wrong!

Regards,
Anz

Answer (score 0):

> JQuery pagination index start from 1
>   means what???
>
> it already started from 1